# почему у меня kali linux на дистрибутиве ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

почему у меня kali linux на дистрибутиве ubuntu?Веть он основан на debian

Comment: Почему вы решили, что у вас kali linux на дистрибутиве ubuntu?